# Validation score during training and checkpoint is different in keras

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, overfitting

I have a tabular data with about 1500 columns where every column except the 1st column is sparse. I am trying to train a Feedforward neural network (1 hidden layer with 32 neurons) for a binary classification problem (20% positive classes) using keras. I use SGD with learning rate 0.1 and momentum 0.9. I am using ROC AUC as the metric and I obtain the curves below:

[image: learning curve]

I use a train/valid/test stratified split. When I evaluate the scores with the saved checkpoints I observe the following values:

[image: table of scores]

Why are the values in the keras model history different from the scores from checkpoints?

How do I find where my model starts overfitting from the curves?